# using embedded graph database in application

Tags: graph-databases, embedded-database

I have a graph that I need to store in an embedded graph database. However, unlike SQLite (or other embedded RDBMS) I haven't really found an example or tutorial explaining how do I get an embedded graph database running in my application.

I've had a look at [Titan-Android](http://wuman.github.io/titan-android/),
[Neo-4j mobile](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android), [Neo4j-embedded](https://github.com/joewhite86/node-neo4j-embedded)

I need to test the embedded database with my application before porting the whole code to the android platform. Hence, I require the use of an embedded graph database.

Comment: by "embedded graph database" do you just mean such that the graph is initialized and managed within the same jvm as your code?

Comment: my (future) target is a smartphone (application?), so I said embedded in that context. It should be packaged and managed within the said application.

Comment: @coolharsh55 did you find a solution? what is your programming language of choice?

Comment: @amirouche No, I eventually gave up. This was I think regarding my Masters research, which I completed using SQLite. I think SQLite itself has grown since then, so should be worth revisiting.

Comment: If you really want a property graphdb like neo4j. You can do that on top of SQLite **OR** on top of SQLite LSM extensions, you can compile it from sqlite3 tree, look into `exts/lsm` inside sqlite3 repository.